# Partial Derivatives - how they work in this examle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the problem $\frac{d}{dt}[p(x(t),t)] = \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}$

Could someone please help me understand why this equality is the case? I imagine it has to do with the chain rule or something but I am having a hard time understanding this idea.

Comment: Are you sure that first partial derivative is with respect to $t$ and not $x$?

Comment: You are right. Sorry I will correct it. I am still not sure why though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a function P(x,y) where x and y are functions of t we have

$$ \frac {d}{dt} P(x,y) =  \frac {\partial p }{ \partial x}   \frac {dx }{dt}+ \frac {\partial p }{ \partial y}   \frac {dy}{dt}$$

your problem is a special case where y=t and as a result you have

$$ \frac {d}{dt} P(x,t) =  \frac {\partial p }{ \partial x}   \frac {dx }{dt}+ \frac {\partial p }{ \partial t}   \frac {dt}{dt}=\frac {\partial p }{ \partial x}   \frac {dx }{dt}+  \frac {\partial p }{ \partial t}   $$

Comment: Thank you so very much. I appreciate your time and help. :)

Comment: @MathIsHard Thanks for your attention and understanding.

Comment: @ Mohammad Riazi-Kermani is this a case of a product rule of some kind?

Comment: Chain rule not product rule.